# How to make thread-safe calls to Windows Forms controls in WPF VB.net

Tags: vb.net, xaml

i'm trying to make a Safe Call to a form control in WPF VB.net and there is no way i can do it. Normally I did it through a delegate but apparently in WPF it is different.
Any ideas?? Greetings.

```
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal text As String)

    Private Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)
            If lProcess.InvokeRequired Then
                Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
                Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {text})
            Else
                Me.lProcess.Text = text
            End If
            Application.DoEvents()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads&p=3783077&viewfull=1#post3783077) of mine. The highlighted post shows how to marshal a method call to the UI thread in a WPF application. Once on that thread, you can access your WinForms control directly. You may like to read the preceding posts for background. Note that the following post provides a means to do the same thing that works in WinForms and WPF from any code, even if that code is not UI-aware, e.g. library code that could be used in applications of both types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare your own delegate. Just use the appropriate `Action` or `Func`. You also don't need to explicitly create an array for the arguments as `Invoke` accepts a `ParamArray`.

```vb
Private Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)
    If Me.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
        'We are on the UI thread.

        Me.lProcess.Text = text
    Else
        'We are on a secondary thread.

        Dim d As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf SetText)

        Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(d, text)
    End If
End Sub
```

That's untested but I think that it should do the job. I've never used a WinForms control in WPF so the line that actually sets the `Text` may not be valid but I'm assuming that you already know how to do that part.

Basically, `Dispatcher.Invoke` is pretty much the same as `Control.Invoke` and `Dispatcher.CheckAccess` is the equivalent of `Control.InvokeRequired` except that the results are reversed.

Comment: Note that comments saying "thanks" or the like are discouraged at SO. Upvoting and accepting answers is the way to say thank you.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. ;)